# Why does repackaging from Android to BlackBerry, version Name changes automatically?

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-10, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have an Android app with versionName=1.0.5 and versionNumber=7 in Android Manifest.xml file. Whenever I repackage my app the vesionName automatically changes to 1.0.7.0. I have no idea why it does this. I want my application versionName to be same as in the Android Manifest.xml file.

Comment: I have found the answer to my question. I found that Blackberry requires x.x.x.x as version name. But I had x.x.x so the repackaging tool changes it. If I had version name as 1. Blackberry repackaging tool will change this to 1.0.0.0 But mine was 1.0.5 which was changed to 1.0.7.0 which is a disappointment, it should have been 1.0.5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to your comment, the convention on BlackBerry platforms is (as you say) to use a dotted quad as the version name. For the sake of discussion lets call the four numbers:

1. Major
2. Minor
3. Release
4. Build

The Major number indicates very significant changes that will often preclude working on older hardware. BBOS 4, 5, 6, 7, 10 are examples of this. A device released to run OS N will usually not be able to run OS N+1.

The Minor numbers indicate significant changes. These are often additional APIs or capabilities but don't usually indicate hardware incompatibilities. For example versions 10.0, 10.1, 10.2 and 10.3.

The Release number indicates changes which are fixes or minor enhancements but don't normally come with major new features or APIs.

The Build number is a one-up number incremented each time the product with a particular Major.Minor.Release is built. It is normal for these numbers to reach the hundreds or thousands before a product is released.

Clearly given a versionNumber to put in the version string with versionName it doesn't make sense to put it in the build field. The Release field makes the most sense.

Comment: Hmm, understood it. But as I had version name as 1.0.5. Its should have been changed to 1.0.5.0. But it changed to 1.0.7.0. And there are no documentation that makes it clear to android developers. Anyways marking this as solved.